# How to get sections from a docx in Java

Tags: java, apache-tika

I am using Apache Tika. For doc files I can get sections of the document using something like:

```
document.getRange().getSection()
```

but this doesn't seem to be the case for docx (using `XWPFDocument`). What is the equivalent for docx using or without using Tika?